# What datastructure should I use to calculate the factorial of a more than 50 digits long number?

Tags: c, data-structures

What are some data structures that help me storing and calculating the factorial for numbers with more than 50 digits?

Comment: Beware that if you want the exact number, you're not going to be able to store the entire number in memory at once, unless you keep a running tally of the number of trailing zeroes. Even then it probably won't fit. For example: [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000!) tells me that there would be 2499999999999999999999999999999999999999999999989 trailing zeroes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try an [Arbitrary Precision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) integer library like [GMP](http://gmplib.org/) or [BigDigits](http://www.di-mgt.com.au/bigdigits.html).

Comment: Can some one help me how to do this without using any library please

Comment: how do you plan to find the memory to do this operation on arbitrary precision integers? It simply isn't possible.

Comment: @mousy, implementing custom multiplication of integers represented as string is a work of 1-2 hours in most programming languages. Go ahead. I did it once. +1 to @drawnonward for mentioning the arbitrary precision.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Stirling formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_formula) to approximate `n!` for large n. Best way to store the number should be [scientific notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation), e.g. `10^(x^y)` for really large numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way maybe it's to use a `char*` that can be as long as you need with no particular contraints and it will have easy management of operations..

Of course this is not the most packed approach but it think it can work quite well if you don't really need efficiency.

EDIT: didn't talk about any lib for bigints just because I thought you did want to know how to do it programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Seen the number of digits that Jamie computed, I guess the number of bits here would be larger than the estimated number of elementary particles in the universe. So this is another way of stating that your problem just don't has a solution in this world as we know it.

Comment: He asked for what you could use, in theory; not sure if it has to be constrained by physical memory limits.

Comment: He didn't phrase (or tag) his question as theoretical but asked for help in realizing this task.